# Should the FAQ on off-topic questions link to other SE sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, off-topic

In the FAQ, there is a [list of concepts that would make a question off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#what-questions-about-code-reviews-are-off-topic). It seems to me like this would be a great place to redirect users to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), as what is off-topic for Code Review is probably a good fit for those sites.

Answer (score 1):

The About page cannot be edited thoroughly enough to link to these sites, nor is it really necessary unless the user posts an off-topic question.

The latest close reasons in effect, which were established [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/revising-list-of-closure-reasons), now include links to both Stack Overflow and Programmers.  When a question is closed, users will know to post on either of these sites.